# Overiding error view on prod in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

Is there a way to override this error message from production to show the stack trace, maybe a way to edit the view?

[image]

We used to have sentry but the company decided to opt-out for some reason and we're having trouble tracing the error on production. The site is for internal use so the domain only works in the company's network.

Also, I was wondering where can I get the top level error on Ruby on Rails like on Express they have this way of handling error in one place.

Nodejs Express example: [express err handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

This way I could send an email to our software team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `exception_handler` gem - https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler

If you do not want to add another dependancy, here is a tutorial on how you can build it yourself - https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/custom-400-500-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails-exception-handler-3a04975e4677

Comment: I was reading about this. thank you.